# Adding $ to a number removes formatting

Tags: vbscript, visual-studio-2017, ssrs-2017

I'm a database guy more than a Programmer, so bear with me. I'm creating a receipt form for a point of sales software, and ran into an issue with formatting my numbers. In the number section of the textbox properties it's formatted to add a comma to any amount over a thousand (the values passed from the data set are Decimal(15,2))

When I print the number on it's own, it's formatted fine. When I add a $ to the beginning through the textbox properties, the commas go away. I assume it's because the number is converted to a string to be concatenated with the $

What I'd like to be able to do is have both the dollar sign, and the number with a comma in one text box. I believe it can be done with an if/else to determine string length, then substringing out the amount and adding commas in the code, but that seems excessively bulky.

Here's the code that prints $1000.00 instead of $1,000.00:

```
="$" & First(Fields!AMOUNT.Value, "DsSalesTicketReport")
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`FormatCurrency()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//k6skb64t%28v%3dvs.85%29)?

Comment: Looks like it. Thank you for the help. Did you want to answer it so I can mark it as closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For formatting a number as currency (per the system's locale) VBScript provides the [`FormatCurrency()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//k6skb64t%28v%3dvs.85%29) function. The result will still be a string, though, so only use this if you don't need to do any calculations with the number.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to add the commas in the SP that the dataset calls from, but I would have run into an issue doing calculations on other parts of my form. this solution works wonderfully for what I needed, thank you.